# Why isn't it possible to download a file for status code 4XX and 5XX

Tags: google-chrome, http, firefox, curl, wget

I have noticed that many http clients including Firefox and Chrome don't allow file downloads for http response codes with 4XX and 5XX. However, some clients allow these downloads, like curl and wget (with `--content-on-error` option).

Both Chrome and Firefox don't provide nice exception messages.
Chrome fails with `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE`. Firefox fails with `File not found`. As stated above for the curly and wget work for the same URL.

I was wondering if there is a specification that defines the correct behavior in this case? Are there good reasons why the request can't be processed by Chrome and Firefox? Also, it seems strange that they don't provide proper feedback.

I think for most cases a download for failing requests makes no sense, but for some cases it would be helpful. One good example where downloading a file even in the error case would be if there is a client that only communicates with the server using some 3rd party format. The client would have to download a generated file for the request. In the case of an error, the client should download a file containing the error description.

For example the [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-17) states

> Response messages with an error status code
> usually contain a payload that represents the error condition, such
> that it describes the error state and what next steps are suggested
> for resolving it.

---

> The 4xx (Client Error) class of status code indicates that the client
> seems to have erred.  Except when responding to a HEAD request, the
> server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the
> error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent
> condition.  These status codes are applicable to any request method.
> User agents SHOULD display any included representation to the user.

This doesn't forbid downloading in the case of an error.

---

**Edit because of the first answer:**

I don't think that this behavior is user friendly and I don't think that user friendliness is really the reason behind this. For example it would make way more sense to show the error code and error message (provided in the header) to the user. Or least indicate the error with an error message like "cannot download the file, because the server responded with an error". There might be servers that can only respond with XML or any other random file format.

What bugs me the most is that both browsers respond with different but arbitrary errors that don't hint any information about the underlying issue.

It might be that this is an undocumented edge case and both Chrome and Firefox just fall back to a default error, but this seems unlikely, especially because this is an edge case that has a special flag in wget.

> 4XX: Why would you assume a file download if your client did something wrong?

If we assume that an API has an endpoint that replies with a certain file format, it is fair to assume that also the error message including a hint what the client did wrong is provided in that format. So the file can help to fix the client error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on [@lossleader's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54754440/1548788), it looks like Chromium decided to follow Firefox's decision to not download files if the response was not successful.

It seems like this issue has a history. In 2005 an AOL website had an issue that returned a status code `500` and resulted in users downloading an `.exe` file. There was a "fix" that simply returns a `404` for responses that trigger a download and with erroneous responses. The corresponding issue can be found [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=312727).

There is an open issue from 2008, that complains about this error and states that it would is misleading. The corresponding issue can be found [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=426961).

I found a more detailed answer about this on [Super User](https://superuser.com/a/719647/182140).

I still think that it would be correct to at least offer a choice to the user to download the file nevertheless or at least show a more meaningful error page. On the other hand, in most cases a download for a response code `!= 2XX` is unintended and hints a server error. Therefore it seems that this issue has a low priority for browser vendors and seems "not worth the trouble".

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of any specification for that topic.
The behavior should be as user friendly as possible.

**4XX:**
Why would you assume a file download if your client did something wrong? Furthermore, the client software could not differ between the case of wrong usage(e.g. invalid url) and handling a file download.

**5xx:**
As you stated most api provide error information, but you could also not differ the case of downloading and for example an internal error providing the file.

You can use such behavior with wget and curl as you mentioned, but its not user friendly nor practical for using such an API programmatically.

The above info in mind, Chrome and firefox just try to be user friendly.

I hope I could somehow answer your question or challenge the idea behind it. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I updated my question. I don't think that this behavior is user friendly at all though.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [chromium handle download and not 2xx](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/content/browser/frame_host/navigation_request.cc?type=cs&q=ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE&sq=package:chromium&g=0&l=1209) we see:

```
  // The response code indicates that this is an error page, but we don't
  // know how to display the content.  We follow Firefox here and show our
  // own error page instead of intercepting the request as a stream or a
  // download.
```

So Chrome followed Firefox, and both are entirely consistent with the RFCs, the browser knows [this payload is unidentified](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.4.1) data relating to an error condition, so saving it as the file in question is not an option. Since it is being downloaded, presumably the browser can't display the payload, but in either case has been instructed not to, so displaying it in the error context is not a safe option. Since it is an error there is also a high likelihood that the sender has combined a partial response with an error code meaning that the payload contents may be an incomplete or corrupt representation of data from a 2xx response/etc.

If you look back at wget, `--content-on-error` is a specific option because it is the wrong thing to do as a general browser. A client side that works with the payload type could examine the errors when it is directly interacting with a server and wget is only providing options to help you debug such an interaction. A normal browser has less features to help emulate other clients for debugging than a text CLI, since a text CLI exists primarily to emulate some other client while debugging.

Comment: The commit http://crrev.com/526475 also includes a discussion that codified Firefox's behavior into the Web Platform Tests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a pity that Chromium followed Firefox. Especially since Firefox's decision seemed like a hot-fix. I just found the relevant issue in Firefox's bugtracker - https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=312727

Answer (score 1):

> I was wondering if there is a specification that defines the correct
>   behavior in this case? Are there good reasons why the request can't be
>   processed by Chrome and Firefox? Also, it seems strange that they
>   don't provide proper feedback.

There is no such specification for this, but the chromium project member finds this as a trivial issue and unlikely to be fixed in near future. Instead of they fixing in the chromium they suggest that it should be fixed on the server by sending proper `HTTP` status.

> **Response from Chromium Project Member:** "*This issue has been Available for over a year. If it's no longer*
>   *important or seems unlikely to be fixed, please consider closing it*
>   *out. If it is important, please re-triage the issue.*"
>
> *Sorry for the inconvenience if the bug really should have been left as*
>   *Available*.

[image]

You can check more details here **[Issue 479265](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=479265&q=ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified)**

**What's happening beneath the surface?**

I further checked the source code of the `chromium` to find what actually happening and found that for any non `200` status for downloads, they are simply throwing `ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE` (Invalid Server Response) error.

[image]

To cut a long story short, **you have to live with this behaviour of the browser**, it is not going to be improved.

Answer (score -1):

These answers all seem to bypass the fundamental here:  You're trying to give a browser-specific interpretation to an error in your code.  From my point of view, in all associated cases, your code is failing in some manner without error handling.

4xx error?  You've sent a bad request to the server, according to rules **you** have determined.  It's not, technically, the browser's fault.

5xx error?  **Your** server crashed and didn't throw a pretty error.  On some types of server, (Django) a 500 error will be a bunch of debug information you probably shouldn't show the user.

Thus what you're asking for is strange from an architectural standpoint; you want to cover up the fact that you've screwed up by modifying the browser's response rather than fixing your code to respond appropriately.

Comment: I disagree about 4XX errors. The spec clearly states: `the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition`. If an API is expected to return a certain file-type, it's fair to assume that it will also return that file type for error cases. 5XX errors are something else and I can understand that the browser won't accept downloads for 5XX responses. On the other hand for 5XX it is common practice to provide an error log id that users can refer to when contacting the support.

Comment: In a modern web application, you have control over what is sent from browser to server.  We're probably not talking about a raw HTTP request here, we're more likely to be addressing some sort of malformed JSON package.  If the user is generating this JSON package on their own, they're either attempting some sort of misuse or your UI is terrible. If this is not the case, the package you're assembling is improperly formed, and the mismatch between expectation and actuality is generally under your control.  The exceptions being network errors, which are rarely seen.

Comment: This question is not about JSON, it's about file downloads.

Comment: What initiates those file downloads, and why are you returning error codes AND a file?

Comment: Exactly that's the question, why one should not return an error code and a file.

Comment: If you're giving someone the appropriate file, the error code is just noise; they've gotten what they asked for, and the browser shouldn't need to get involved - your server-side logs should.  If you're not giving someone the appropriate file, why are you giving them the file in the first place?  It seems to me you might want to look for different codes rather than stuff whatever communication you want into codes defined for your use as, 'System Errors Here, Dig.'  There are lots of non-fatal messages to choose from, why not use them?